# Can not add data into database using jquery ajax with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to store data into database using jquery ajax using php but when i click on submit button a empty alert shows up and a message below submit button submitted succesfully but no data is added on my databse.i am at very beginer level in jquery and ajax...Any Help will be appreciated.

Here is my HTML

```
<form method="POST" >
        <pre>
            <label for="">Enter Post Topic</label><input type="text" id="txt_topic_name" name="txt_topic_name"><br>
            <label for="">Enter Detail</label><textarea id="txt_detail" name="txt_detail"></textarea><br/>
            <label for=""></label><input type="button" id="btn_submit" name="btn_submit" value="submit"><br>
        </pre>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

And here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_submit').on('click',function(){
            var topic_name = $('#txt_topic_name').val();
            var detail     = $('#txt_detail').val();
            $.ajax({
                url   : "ajax/add_topic.php",
                type  : "POST",
                data  : {'txt_topic_name' : topic_name ,'txt_detail' : detail},
                success : function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#results').html("submitted succesfully");
                },
                error  : function(data){
                    // alert(data);
                    // console.log(data);
                }

            });
             // return false;

        });

     });
```

And PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not coonnect");
    mysql_select_db("forum") or die("could not select db");

    $topic_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txt_topic_name']);
    $detail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txt_detail']);

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO Topics(name,detail)  VALUES('$topic_name','$detail')";
    $query  = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($query) {
        echo "Sucess";
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed";

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: You can't able to use Form Submit and Ajax both at same time... Both are different from each other

Comment: No error just a alert pops up from success function and displays nothing

Comment: @AntoKing that was only a button not the submit button

Comment: so how should i do it can you explain it... Anto King

Comment: @AntoKing  Sudhanshu Saxena is right it's not a submit button

Comment: `if ($query) {
        echo $query;
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed";

    }`
so that you can see what query is running and try to fire directly.

Comment: Your code looks fine just check whethr data is available in var topic_name &  var detail

Comment: are you saying i should var_dump(topic_name)  @Anto King

Comment: it stil displays nothing @ Anto King....

Comment: You can just put debug break point in console and check whether data is availble is it there try to use the answer posted by Xlander

Comment: @ Anto King  can you tell me at which line should i use debbuger....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['txt_topic_name'])) {
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not coonnect");
    mysql_select_db("forum") or die("could not select db");

    $topic_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txt_topic_name']);
    $detail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txt_detail']);

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO Topics(name,detail)  VALUES('$topic_name','$detail')";
    $query  = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($query) {
        echo "Sucess";
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed";

    }

}
```

Comment: Feel free to add some text to explain what you did and why.

Comment: Thnx Man it's added in the database.Can you plz explain to me what was i doing wrong.

Comment: @Er. Sajal Tiwari can you please explain it what i did wrong.?

Comment: actually you are posting the following data 'txt_topic_name' : topic_name ,'txt_detail' : detail ,and in your php file yor are catching button which has not been posted.

Answer (score 0):

The data object should be like this

```
data: {txt_topic_name : topic_name ,txt_detail : detail}
```

instead of this

```
data: {'txt_topic_name' : topic_name ,'txt_detail' : detail}
```

And for a better check for a post, use a hidden input

```
<input type='hidden' value='true' name='submission' />
```

Then in php check for `submission`

```
if(isset($_POST['submission']) && $_POST['submission'] == 'true'){
  //the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: it still displays nothing on alert

Comment: @Xlander _The data object should be like this..._ Both are the same

Comment: Have you include `submission: 'true'` in the data object?

Comment: @hindmost: Hmmm... Well, I used to write it this way :p... nevermind.

Comment: `data: {txt_topic_name : topic_name ,txt_detail : detail, submission: $('input[name="submission"]').val()}`

Then in your success function, check for the value `data`:
`if(data == 'Sucess') $('#results').html("submitted succesfully");
else $('#results').html("error");`